# What URL does Recovery HD connect to in order to download OS X?

Tags: macos, network, install, recovery-hd

My college Wi-Fi Network doesn't support OS X reinstalls through Recovery HD. If I were to ask the people in charge of our Network to manually enable access to Apple's Servers so that I could do reinstalls over Wi-Fi, what would I need to tell them to allow?

Comment: Since the Network Administrator is already disallowing OS X Internet Recovery Mode to begin with, he/she probably doesn't need you to tell  him/her anything as he/she could change whatever is already being blocked.

Comment: @user3439894 - you're assuming it's intentionally blocked. I'd suggest on a campus network that it's something that no-one has yet thought to open. Same result, different reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: [OS X: Ports and hosts used by OS X Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202481)

> In order to reinstall OS X using the OS X Recovery or Lion Internet
>   Recovery, you must be able to connect to the Internet. If your
>   computer is behind an external proxy server or firewall, your network
>   administrator will need to ensure that you can resolve DNS for the
>   following hosts and contact them on ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS):
>
> osrecovery.apple.com
>   oscdn.apple.com
>
> Note: Each hostname may resolve to a different IP address each time it
>   is used.

Answer (score 1):

Checking a virtual El Capitan Recovery HD trying to restore El Capitan with WireShark a lot more hosts are involved:

```
swscan.apple.com
sr.symcd.com
s2.symcd.com
osrecovery.apple.com
oscdn.apple.com
init.itunes.apple.com
xp.apple.com
buy.itunes.apple.com
sb.symcd.com
evsecure-ocsp.verisign.com
osxapps.itunes.apple.com
init-cdn.itunes-apple.com.akadns.net
mzuserxp.itunes-apple.com.akadns.net
```

Some of them are aliases to akamaiedge.net or edgekey.net hosts.

The ports needed are 53 (dns), 80 (http) and 443 (https).

Comment: Since the requirement are as stated in my answer, an excerpt of an official Apple support document, I'd venture to say as long as those requirements are met the recovery would proceed regardless of what Wireshark shows on an unfettered connection.